# File Access Permissions

Tags: php, apache, ftp

Please can someone confirm that '000' access permissions for admin files is secure?

I want to securely store private data on the server.

Comment: If you never want anyone to access them at all ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file has permission 000,
then mathematically it means that 666-000=666 permission means only accessed by super user but will not get execute permissions.
Owner of that file can access that file but after the permissions being changed.

Answer (score 0):

000 won't give anyone or anything access, including you, or even root.

Comment: Sorry about that then. Should read up on permissions some more.

Comment: You're mostly correct; root just gets a special exception for reads.  They can always `chmod` anything anyway.